# reverse scrolling on iphone

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, desktop

I'm having trouble accomplishing reverse scrolling in mobile devices.
When users scroll down, so does the whole page scrolls the same way as opposed to the way it normally works. It works perfectly on desktop but it doesn't on my phone.

this is a JSFiddle from Rohit Agrawal which is exactly what I'd like to have it both on desktop and on my phone. http://jsfiddle.net/5UUtV/1/

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/5UUtV/1/][http://jsfiddle.net/5UUtV/1/]
```

Thanks in advance!